# Spring Batch Job Scope Unavailable

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

It seems like the Spring Batch 3.0.6 release points to the 2.2 schema by default.

In the spring.schemas file there is this definition

`http\://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd=/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/spring-batch-2.2.xsd`

And when I add this namespace to my spring file, I then get the `scope="step"` option (in my IDE, although IntelliJ has been pretty reliable matching runtime issues)

```
...
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
...
```

But everything seems to claim that `scope="job"` is invalid.

**Is it the spring.schemas file doing this? Why would the 3.xx iteration point back to the 2.2 schemas?**

I can't seem to get a declaration like `xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd"` to work. Surprisingly that totally invalidates the batch namespace. Even though the `spring.schemas` file points to 3.xx like so

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd=/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
```

If I do this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
      ...
 </beans>
```

I can then get the `scope="step"` to be valid, and everything seems to point to `batch-3.0`, but `scope="job"` is still invalid.

Does anyone have a clean example of importing batch & using a job scope declaration on a bean?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a bug.  I've created this issue in Jira to track: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2477

Comment: Thank you @MichaelMinella! Do you think this is what is causing my inability to get Job as a valid scope value in my XML configuration?